# AWS instance access error : The server requested closed the connection before the transaction

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I have couple of questions bothering me and would like some help here of all the awesome experienced people over here.

1) I am facing this specific issue whenever I access phpMyAdmin hosted on AWS ec2 t2.medium instance (not frequently though but I feel the android app which accesses REST API to upload file to ec2 server fails to upload file and I think it's causing because of the below network drop maybe, not sure as I am new to AWS):

> The server requested closed the connection before the transaction

My AWS instance is running:

1. UBUNTU
2. APACHE server
3. Laravel 5.3 for backend and REST API
4. 1 instance of ec2 t2.medium server
5. 2 EBS volumes of i) 10 GB and ii) 20 GB
6. no loadbalancer is being used as of now

2) I am new to using AWS and have successfully deployed my Laravel based backend on AWS and my android app access the REST API hosted on same ec2 t2.medium instance. Now what bothers me is, I am not sure how it will be auto scalable? because the app is downloaded by more than 7000 users+ when we run our marketing campaign which has been stopped now because many users face issue while uploading the media file to the server, after certain %ge the file stops to upload file and rest users are able to upload file.

The android app does everything good but most people face issue when they try to upload the file to a REST API url coded in Laravel hosted on AWS ec2 t2.medium instance and I am using the below android library to upload file to my server through my backend's file upload API :

https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

The file upload laravel API i've constructed is like this:

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request, userSubmitData $udb)
{

    $creds = $request->all();

    $idFromDB = $udb::where('token', $creds['token'])->value('token');
    $uid = $udb::where('token', $creds['token'])->value('user_id');
    $hasFile = "false";
        $file = $request->file('myFile');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = $uid."_".$fileName;
        Storage::disk('local')->put($fileName,  File::get($file));
        $udb->where('token', $creds['token'])->update(['fileHandle' => $fileName, 'mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(), 'original_filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'approved' => NULL, 'rejected' => NULL]);
        $hasFile="1";
    return Response($hasFile, 200);
}
```

Please give me your insight in to building scalable technology and setting up AWS efficiently as fault tolerant, highly scalable and highly availbale architecture and technology.

Thank You.

*PS: I am not a great coder or anything, just a novice architect who loves coding and building beautiful things, there are far great and amazing people than me out there haha. So never mind the way I am executing things here I am just in process of making things work right way thats all and make it work beautifully :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two options I can propose to you, both will give you the scalability you need as well as the fault tolerance you require. It's a bit wordy but I implore you to read your way through and feel free to ask follow up questions! :)

**Option one - Route53, ELBs, ASGs and redundancy.**

For this solution you will need to make use of Route53 health checks, an Elastic Load Balancer and an Auto Scaling Group.

The Stack:

1. [Route53 DNS]
2. [Elastic Load Balancer]
3. [Auto Scaling Group]
4. [Application Instances]

Route53 will provide your DNS needs to the load balancer, however it can also give you some very nice health checks and auto fail-over capability. Depending on your own acceptable level of fault tolerance in your High Availability Strategy, you can use this health check to evaluate the overall health of it's target (in this case the ELB) and fail over DNS to an alternate stack that you have at all time running and standing by. This could be expensive but it depends on your business case.

The Elastic Load Balancer will target instances in your Auto Scaling Group, you should configure your Auto Scaling Group to make use of at least 2 Availability Zones. This means if an AZ fails your application remains available to your clients. It's extremely unusual for more than one AZ to fail at the same time, but it could happen. It's also important to be aware that when an AZ fails the remaining AZs will become oversubscribed very quickly. This means that if you are using 2 AZs and one of them fails, that means that your application will be running at 50% diminished capacity and due to everyone running from the failing AZ to the remaining ones, chances are your Auto Scaling Group will struggle to automatically provision additional instances in that AZ. So if your applications high availability is as paramount as your ability to serve your customers at premium quality it means based on a scenario where you are using 2 AZs you would need to provision 100% of your BAU capacity in each AZ. You can reduce this to a smaller percentage if you wish to gamble on the possibility that you will be able to provision some replacement instances in your remaining AZ if one of your AZs fails. Alternatively you can make use of another AZ (total of 3+).

I could talk for days about this, but moving on...

Lastly are your Application Instances. You need to create a script that will take them from the Ubuntu AMI of your choice right through to production ready. The Auto Scaling Group will start new instances with this script in the Instance's UserData metadata and the Instance will consume this to become ready. Without this script you would have to manually setup and configure every instance that your Auto Scaling Group creates, this isn't ideal.

***Important:*** Just in case, if you application cannot scale because of session states in memory then you have a problem you need to remedy. There are a few ways to do this but the Amazon way is to make use of ElastiCache for session storage. Might be a little work but it will make your solution far more resilient.

This will create a Highly Available solution for your application but is reliant on you making some business decisions on cost vs HA.

**Option 2 - A True Cloud and AWS approach, Serverless.**

From the above you can quickly see just how expensive it can be to take an application, place it in the cloud and maintain a high level of HA and QOS. However there is a better, cheaper and less maintenance approach available to you at the cost of initial redevelopment of some parts of your application - A Serverless Design.

For this you would effectively do away with your application servers and make use of the following products:

1. AWS Lambda
2. AWS DynamoDB or Amazon RDS (depending on your need, however I'd shoot for DynamoDB if you can.)
3. Amazon API Gateway

Replacing your application logic and dependency on instance with Lambda will see you be able to execute your code without having to be concerned about AZs, ELBs, ASGs, Redundancy and over subscription upon failure. Lambda is extremely cost competitive and I dare to say will not even be a fraction of the cost of running instance applications with all the HA configurations etc.

Using API Gateway you can expose your Lambda functions to your users in a manageable, highly available way with very little effort and cost compared to the option above.

DynamoDB is the NoSQL offering by AWS. Its HA, fast and easily tailored by yourself to be as resourced as you need it to be. An alternative is Amazon RDS which will give you a more traditional SQL experience but at the end of the day you are still paying for instances in a cluster plus a small fee for the management.

I will summarize by saying, Option 2 is where you should be aiming however given you already have a product that is written and servicing clients you should go ahead with Option 1 for now and obtain that HA and scalable confidence and then project Option 2 for later.

Here is some additional reading on all the topics I have discussed, but feel free to ask more questions if you need.

**Option 1 Documentation**

Route53 Health Checks and Fail-over
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html

Elastic Load Balancer
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elastic-load-balancing/

Auto Scaling Groups (please also checkout Launch Configurations)
https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html

AWS ElastiCache
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elasticache/

**Option 2 Documentation**

Amazon API Gateway
https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

AWS Lambda
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/

AWS DynamoDB
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/dynamodb/

Amazon RDS
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/rds/

Cheers,

Xavier

Comment: Thank you so much @Xavier Hutchinson for taking the time out and explaining me about building scalable fault tolerant architecture. I am looking in to it to build my startup's app service and although I am a full stack dev but I have just started my journey as Technology Architect and I am super grateful to you and Stackoverflow community for coming to my rescue. :)